# Adding SVG element to an html file?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add some SVG elements to an html file. I'm finding links which say this is not supported, the document type must be xhtml.

But I am using some javascript libraries with html that allow me to use SVG in them (Raphael, SVG Web, etc).

So is there a way to add a script to an html file which can dynamically add an SVG element to the document at run time?

Thanks

Comment: I can use any doc type (i'm not up to speed with doc types) - this is just for a proof of concept, so I can use whatever doc type works, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var svgnode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
circle.setAttribute("cx", "100");
circle.setAttribute("cy", "100");
circle.setAttribute("r", "40");
circle.setAttribute("fill", "blue");

svgnode.appendChild(circle);
mydiv.appendChild(svgnode);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), which allows you to put SVG directly into a `<script>` tag in HTML. It will also emulate SVG support using Flash for browsers which do not have native SVG support.

**edit**: Hmm. I just noticed that you mentioned svgweb already. In what way does it not do what you want? You might want to clarify your question.